# NG-Repeat don't work when I upgrade AngularJS v1.0.x to Angular 1.3.14

Tags: angularjs

In 2012 I took the "angular Phonecat tutorial" which is on the Angular homepage 
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

and changed a things like the text in the json-file (which is included in this tutorial), so it worked on my [webpage](http://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm2003/beauty_arrangementen_vergelijker.html).

I just downloaded and put the whole tutorial on my site, which included the angular.js (version 1.0.2)

Now I simply replace the line

```
<script src="../app/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

(this is version 1.0.2 as it was provide in the tutorial) 
with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And the webpage isn't work anymore.
I've reread the tuturial and probably they have changed things in it, but I can't figure out what the difference is between these two versions.

Here is some code:

```
<ul class="phones">
  <li ng-repeat="arr in arrangementen | filter:value1| filter:value2|filter:value3| filter:value21| filter:value4| filter:value5| filter:query | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail">
    <a href="{{arr.link}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{arr.imageUrl}}"></a>
    <!-- <p><b>{{arr.name}}</b> </p> -->
    <p><a href="{{arr.link}}">  {{arr.name}}    </a>         € {{arr.prijs| number : 2}}</p>  
    <p>{{arr.omschrijving1}}</p>            
    <p>Inhoud: {{arr.omschr_inh}}  <a href="{{arr.link}}">  meer</a></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the controllers.js

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

function ArrangemtenListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('angular/arrangementenkiezer/app/data/arrangementen.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.arrangementen = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = 'prijs';
}

//PhoneListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

Comment: I think you can show us some codes or fiddle

Comment: I just edited the question, and add some relevant code.

Comment: ng-app="" in your beauty_arrangementen_vergelijker.html

Comment: ng-app='"  
the controller is called in the body-tag. Like this. 
<body ng-controller="ArrangemtenListCtrl">
I've no idea what I should put in ng-app right now

Comment: you should define an angular module and set the ngApp with the module name that you assign

Comment: I just notice some console errors. I look this up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an angular module like this below, and have your controller set.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
     .controller('ArrangemtenListCtrl', ArrangemtenListCtrl);
```

In HTML you can then set the ng-app in the html tag itself

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Follow the link to read [more on angular modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Comment: This is the solution. You need to declare the module in the newer versions. Thank you for your help